# python VSCode debug not loading

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I try to start the debugger by pressing the green play button. However, it doesn't start the process? The blue slider keeps loading but it never starts Debugging. This is specific to Python as, when I have Debugged C or C++, it works just fine. I am using the Python:current file configuration, but none of the configurations start the Debug process. 
[Picture of the Debug button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJfQR.png)

There isn't even an error message; it just doesn't want to start the Debug process. The following is my launch.json file (note: this has worked before and has since been unchanged):

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}"
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "port": 3000,
        "secret": "my_secret",
        "host": "localhost"
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Terminal (integrated)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Terminal (external)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "externalTerminal"
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
        "args": [
            "runserver",
            "--noreload",
            "--nothreading"
        ],
        "debugOptions": [
            "RedirectOutput",
            "Django"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Flask (0.11.x or later)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "flask",
        "env": {
            "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceFolder}/app.py"
        },
        "args": [
            "run",
            "--no-debugger",
            "--no-reload"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Module",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "module.name"
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Pyramid",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "args": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/development.ini"
        ],
        "debugOptions": [
            "RedirectOutput",
            "Pyramid"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Watson",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/console.py",
        "args": [
            "dev",
            "runserver",
            "--noreload=True"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: All debug Options",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "module": "module.name",
        "env": {
            "VAR1": "1",
            "VAR2": "2"
        },
        "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        "args": [
            "arg1",
            "arg2"
        ],
        "debugOptions": [
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Here is the automatically generated terminal command when pressing the debug button:

```
PS C:\Users\surya\OneDrive - King's College London\MoreDHCPdata> cd 'c:\Users\surya\OneDrive - King's College London\MoreDHCPdata'; ${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; & 'C:\Users\surya\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\surya\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.3.1\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_launcher.py' 'c:\Users\surya\OneDrive - King''s College London\MoreDHCPdata' '51293' '34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14' 'RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput' 'c:\Users\surya\OneDrive - King''s College London\MoreDHCPdata\tester2.py'
```

> >

Of course, there are no outputs on messages in the Debug console as it fails to even start debugging...

Note: The Debugger has worked fine in the past for Python, it just doesn't want to debug anymore, hence this post.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing the extension? There has been a rash of partial upgrades as of late and this is one way the issue manifests itself.

Comment: I have tried that many times. I completely removed all packages, reinstalled VSCode and then reinstalled the packages. I removed all the edited settings from the settings.json files to reset the settings to default.

Comment: Can you open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python ?

Comment: I've already opened it, but no replies were made

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same thing which got fixed by adding **C:\Windows\System32** in the path variable under environmental variables(same place where we add path for python).

It might be the same thing with you as well. If not, try to debug the program in **Python:Terminal(Integrated)** as it threw me an error *'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

Check if you get any similar error or something different.